# How do you type in this? (math mode)

Tags: math-mode

I've been typing up a document, and I realized I didn't know how to type up this sideways parenthesis thing here:[image]

Could someone tell me how to type that up? This is in math mode.

Comment: $a^n=\underbrace{a\times a\times\dots\times a}_n$

Comment: @marmot The answer section is below.